# Using grep to find a word containing only one time a letter

Tags: linux, grep

I have a text file containing the following words :

```
White 
Pinkman 
Goodman 
White 
Pinkman 
Fring
```

I want to use grep to obtain the words that contain the letter "n" only one time.

I used the following command : `grep -E 'n{1}'`
but it still gives me the words that contain "n" more than one time.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works for me:
grep "^[^n]*n[^n]*$"

Comment: It worked for me aswell. Tank you good Sir!